# How can I simulate network replies on an Android unit testing project?

Tags: android, testing, junit, instrumentation

I am testing an Android Library project which rely on the network connection. I would like to simulate http replies from the network. By reading the Android documentation, I have not found any solution. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Do the Robolectric samples not help? https://github.com/robolectric/RobolectricSample/tree/master/src/test/java/com/pivotallabs

Comment: I have tried but I ran into other issues as Robolectric runs on the JVM instead of Davlik.

Comment: I took from the use of the tag you were using Robolectric...so are you just looking for any way to test your code that makes network requests making no restrictions to technology used to do so?